# how to show breadcrumbs only on subpage?

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

How can I show breadcrumbs only when the depth level is more than 2.

i.e.:

1. home > page > subpage => show breadcrumb
2. home > page => hide breadcrumb

Additionally I would like to hide 'home' also (and always), but this has less priority in my question.

Thanks for your explanation!

Regards,
Hans

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Drupal 7, then you can use:

- [Path Breadcrumbs](https://drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs)
- [Context path breadcrumb](https://drupal.org/project/context_path_breadcrumb)

> Path breadcrumbs module helps you to create breadcrumbs for any page with any selection rules and load any entity from the URL!
>
> [image: screenshot]

> This is a plugin module for the context module. It takes the request URI part of the URL of the current page (for example /our-company/our-team/steve) and uses this path to build the breadcrumbs.
>
> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to use the [Custom Breadcrumbs](https://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) module:

> Allows administrators to set up parametrized breadcrumb trails for any
>   node type. This allows CCK-style node types to have `Home > User Blog >
>   2005 > January` style breadcrumbs on the node view page itself, synchronizing cleanly with custom views or pathauto aliases.
>   Breadcrumb visibility can be customized via a php snippet.

Comment: Custom Breadcrumbs is very likely to be deprecated in favour of [Path Breadcrumbs](https://drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs), so I would avoid it.